# Does the digital download "World of Warcraft" on the blizzard store include the base game, BC, WotLK and Cata?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Because I [don't see those expansions listed individually](http://puu.sh/aFTAk/4025796e65.jpg), just World of Warcraft, WoW: Warlords of Draenor and WoW: Mists of Pandaria.
The expansions aren't listed in the [WoW product details](https://eu.battle.net/shop/en/product/world-of-warcraft#techspecs) either.

Is it reasonable to assume that the "World of Warcraft" listed on [that page](https://eu.battle.net/shop/en/product/game/wow?categories=digital-games%2Cgame-time) includes the unlisted expansions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purchasable base game description says it includes levels 1-85, meaning it includes the base game, TBC, WotLK and Cataclysm.

It does not include the latest expansion- Mists of Pandaria (levels 86-90). It does not include Warlords of Draenor because it hasn't been released yet- the purchase on the site is for pre-ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the base game includes the first three expansions.

On the product details page from your link:

> Includes levels 1–85

Which means all expansions upto Cataclysm (Level 85).